# insert to mysql from ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi i am trying to insert data to mysql from ajax with php here is my code can anyone help.
The only error i get is that the data is not insert, in my mysql the values is not pass in.
Where is the problem in my ajax? 
or in my php when i pass values.

index.php

```
<?php include "bd.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Submit Form Using AJAX and jQuery</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
    integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container ">

    <form class="form-signin text-center col-md-6" method="post" action="">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Insert value in</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="last_name" class="sr-only">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="sr-only">email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone" class="sr-only">Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="bridge">Select list:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="bridge" name="bridge">
                <option>None</option>
                <option>eAgent</option>
                <option>iArts</option>
                <option>Orbit</option>
                <option>G&G</option>
                <option>EstateWeb</option>
                <option>Globalc</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comments">Comment:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" >Register</button>
    </form>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Here is tha form with ajax.</h2>

    </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").serialize();
            var last_name = $("#last_name").serialize();
            var email = $("#email").serialize();
            var phone = $("#phone").serialize();
            var bridge = $("#bridge").serialize();
            var comments = $("#comments").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url     : "ajax.php",
                data    : {'name': name,'email': email ,'last_name':last_name,'phone':phone,'bridge': bridge, 'comments': comments},

                success : function(result) {
                    alert(result);

                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now my file of php where the connection is done.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: erevos13
 * Date: 26/6/2017
 * Time: 11:13 μμ
 */
//is the databases connection
include "bd.php";

if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $bridge = $_POST['bridge'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO info (`id` , `name`, `last_name`, `email `, `phone`, `bridge` , `comments` ) VALUES ( '' , '" . $name . "', '" . $last_name . "','" . $email . "', '" . $phone . "' , '" . $bridge . "', '" . $comments . "')";

    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if ($query) {
        echo "data insert successfully";
    } else {
        echo "data is not insert";
    }

}
```

The only error i get is the "data is not insert".

Comment: remove the id from columns and the blank from the values and check.

Comment: try echo query and paste it into phpmyadmin, also remove id column from the query as that is not required it will take value automatically as it is auto-increment

Comment: still nothing .. where is the glitch?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `console.log()` function to check the data in the javascript code.
And read a little bit more about `serialize` function at [here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).
Your javascript code should be something like:

```
$.ajax({
   type    : "POST",
   url     : "ajax.php",
   data    : $("form").serialize();
```

Comment: in my console.log is the say the same:
Data is insert from php file

Answer (score 0):

Try `val()` in place of `serialize()`.Check code for jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var phone = $("#phone").val();
            var bridge = $("#bridge").val();
            var comments = $("#comments").val();

            $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url     : "ajax.php",
                data    : {'name': name,'email': email ,'last_name':last_name,'phone':phone,'bridge': bridge, 'comments': comments},

                success : function(result) {
                    alert(result);

                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: i use val but still, is popup in alert from jquery the echo "Data is not insert"

Comment: remove `id` parameter from insert query.

Comment: i did that and still in not passing the values in my batabases

Comment: run query in phpmyadmin sql `INSERT INTO info(id, name,last_name, email, phone, bridge,comments) VALUES ('','test','test','test@test.test','1234567890','test','test')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` function instead `.serialize()`, if you have value of name is `niklesh` it will give `name=niklesh` and you expect only `niklesh` here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var phone = $("#phone").val();
            var bridge = $("#bridge").val();
            var comments = $("#comments").val();
            $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url     : "ajax.php",
                data    : {"name": name,"email": email ,"last_name":last_name,"phone":phone,"bridge": bridge, "comments": comments},
                success : function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Also use parameterised mysqli :

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every one i found all the problem it was in :

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO info ( name, last_name, email , phone, bridge, comments ) VALUES (  '{$name}' , ' {$last_name} ','{$email }', '{$phone}' , '{$bridge}','{$comments}')";
```

I manage to find put in this in my code.:

```
mysqli_error($connection)
```

and i find that the mysql it was not insert one row.
I fix that and all is good.